# Vim: mapping tab to ctrl space only if the cursor is in front of a non whitespace character

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, autocmd, plugin-jedi-vim

I am using the jedi-vim extension and really don't like pressing ctrl-space to bring up auto-complete. I would like to use tab, but also obviously when coding I need tab for indentation as well.

I know that I will pretty much never press tab with the purpose of indenting when the character before my cursor is not a whitespace character. How can I map tab to ctrl space in this setting?

I only want it to apply in the case of a python file, and only in the current buffer (so if I change buffers the mapping disappears)

Comment: "but also obvioulsy when coding I need tab for indentation as well" - I don't mean to interfere with your coding habits but ... I actually never press tab for indentation. Ideally, vim should do the indentation for you based on `autoindent`, `smartindent` and the like. For cases when it's not working, use `=`, `<` and `>` to indent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually looks like I figured something out. Other people porbably know better. But this seems to work for me:

```
" Map tab to ctrl space in python files when you have something other than
" whitespace
function NoAutoComplete()
    if getline(".")[col(".")-2] == " " || col(".") == 1
        return 1
    endif
endfunction 
autocmd FileType python imap <buffer> <expr> <Tab> NoAutoComplete() ? "\<TAB>" : "\<C-@>"
```

Note: I believe the map must be recursive to properly map ctrl space to what jedi-vim uses. Furthermore I have these settings for my "normal tab" so that the function only needs to check for spaces:

```
" show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4

" when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
set shiftwidth=4

" On pressing tab, insert 4 spaces
set expandtab
```

Comment: So you can mark your problem as solved by accepting your own response (tick on the side.) Welcome vi.SE

Comment: Can't do that until tomorrow it says